# Am looking for an equivalent function for FDIST in python

Tags: python, django, excel, python-2.7

I am not a statistician or anything like that. I am working on a project where I got an excel file and I need to replicate the same actions that are made in the file to an html table.

I got most of the file right but am stuck on a function called FDIST which as I tried to understand means the function probability distribution. Now I tried to look for something that does the same thing in python (because I am using django as the server side) I came across the scipy library which helped a lot in the other actions I needed to do, but still I can't find something that does what FDIST in excel do. I found a function f.pdf but turns out it is not the same.

Can someone suggest a way to get the same result?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution) to know more about F distribtion in general.

If you use the parameters `x = 2.510, dfn = 3, dfd = 48` in Excel, you get:

[image: FDIST in Excel]

Note that FDIST is available for compatibility with Excel 2007 and earlier, and was replaced by F.DIST (with `Cumulative = True`)

Using [scipy.stats](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.f.html) you get the same results:

```
>>>from scipy.stats import f
>>>x = 2.510
>>>dfn = 3
>>>dfd = 48

>>>f.cdf (x, dfn, dfd)
0.930177201089
>>>1- f.cdf (x, dfn, dfd)
0.0698227989112
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I use the following values, x = 2.510, dfn = 3, dfd = 48. on excel I get 0.069822799 and on python I get 0.081155460037725474 .
Is that suppose to be right?

Comment: @Yousef_Shamshoum I edited my answer, I thought you were using F.DIST